# WPF Devexpress ComboBoxEdit Items

Tags: wpf, combobox, devexpress

i use devexpress comboBoxEdit component in my WPF app. I assign values for it like this:

```
private void Users1_Load()
{
    DataTable dtCat = SqlHelper.GetTable("base_UserCategory_Select", new string[] { });
    DataRow dr = dtCat.NewRow();
    dr["UserCategoryID"] = 0;
    dr["CategoryName"] = "< All >";
    dr["IsSystem"] = "False";
    dtCat.Rows.InsertAt(dr, 0);
    comboBoxEdit1.ItemsSource = dtCat.DefaultView;
    comboBoxEdit1.SelectedIndex = 1;
}
```

My xaml:

```
<dxe:ComboBoxEdit Height="20" Margin="14,64,0,0" Name="comboBoxEdit1" DisplayMember = "CategoryName" ValueMember = "UserCategoryID" VerticalAlignment="Top" xmlns:dxe="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/editors" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="254" />
```

But the problem is, that in this combobox i see my id's (Value Members), only when i expand it, then i see DisplayMember values. Whats the problem, how to do to allways see text values, not my id's..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the

```
IsTextEditable="False"
```

to your xaml for the ComboBoxEdit. This is a known issue with the control, [mentioned here](http://devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/B150063.aspx). I use DX controls, and personally i think their Silverlight and WPF controls are a long way behind the rest of the market (their Silverlight controls are still beta, arguably when the ComboBoxEdit contains a bug like this then the WPF controls should be considered beta too). You might want to stick to the MS controls until DX fix their crap.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the ansver and the solution. Seems Devexpress have some seriuos crap's.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a more complex behaviour, you can use the DevExpress LookUpEdit component http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/clsDevExpressXtraEditorsLookUpEdittopic